# Importando biblioteca no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Como importar um biblioteca no Android Studio?

Tenho um projeto no Eclipse que utiliza as bibliotecas:

- zip_file
- library
- downloader_library

necessarias para adicionar [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) a uma aplicação que tem mais de 50MB.

O projeto esta funcionando normalmente no Eclipse, gostaria de adiciona-lo ao Android Studio e não sei como, já baixei o:

- Google Play APK Expansion Library
- Google Play Licensing Library
- Android Support Library

no Android SDK Manager.

Comment: Não sei se isso responde a sua pergunta, mas de uma olhada ai https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767782/importing-eclipse-project-into-android-studio-getbuildscript-error

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Em um projeto que estou fazendo tive um certa dificuldade para adicionar `Bibliotecas` do tipo **não`.JAR`**, pois a cada versão que o [Android Studio IDE](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent) atualiza alguma coisa muda. E a mudança da  [versão 0.3.0](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudio030released) removeu opções do menu `Project Structure`, facilitando de um lado e dificultando por outro.

---

Vou mostrar passo-a-passo como fiz para adicionar o pacote **`zip_file`** da library: `Google Play APK Expansion Library`;

*Observação: Utilizei a versão 0.3.7 do Android Studio*

1. No Android Studio acesse o menu `Project Structure`: [image: imagem passo 1] ou   `Cmd + ;` (no mac)
2. No menu que aparecer você verá apenas um `Modulo` do seu projeto
   [image: imagem passo 2]
3. Na aba `Dependencies` adicione uma dependência Maven: *Explico o motivo >> Como falei anteriormente que eles removeram algumas opções do menu, tive que forçar um erro nas minhas dependências para poder visualizar o menu de forma antiga, podendo assim adicionar novas bibliotecas ao meu modulo principal <<* Para isso basta digitar `gms` e adicionar qualquer uma das opções de dependência que aparecer, no meu caso `org.shoal:shoal-gms:1.5@jar`

   [image: imagem passo 3]
4. Feito isto reinicie o `Android Studio` e volte no menu `Project Structure` (ver passo 1) e você verá o seguinte erro: [image: imagem passo 4]

   *Observação: Caso não apareça o erro na primeira vez, reinicie novamente, no meu caso apareceu na 2x que reiniciei.*
5. No erro acima clique neste ícone [image: imagem passo 5]
6. Note que a janela de `Modulo` ficará diferente agora [image: imagem passo 6]
7. Agora basta clicar em qualquer um dos outros pacotes e depois clicar na lupa, e depois selecionar seu projeto principal

   [image: imagem passo 7]
8. E finalmente a as opções que estavam escondidas!! [image: imagem passo 8]
9. Clique no `+` e depois em `Import Module`

   [image: imagem passo 9]
10. Siga os passos de import e por fim você terá um novo modulo no seu projeto.

    [image: imagem passo 10]

    *Observações finais: Realmente é um processo trabalhoso, talvez eles melhorem em outras versões ou deixem os menus de maneira visível.*

    *Não esqueça de remover a dependência que adicionou no Passo 3...*

Comment: É isso mesmo funcionou aqui comigo. vllw

Comment: A solução indicada pelo TSangar, não funciona para a versão mais recente do Android Studio (não aparece o erro no passo 4).
Alguém já consegui fazer isto nesta versão mais recente? Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Se a biblioteca for um JAR faça o seguinte:

1) Copie o arquivo JAR para o diretório `<diretorio do projeto>/libs`
2) No Android Studio, na estrutura do projeto, entre na pasta `libs`, selecione a biblioteca que você acabou de adicionar, clique no menu de contexto (botão direito do mouse) e selecione a opção `Add as Library...`

Existe outra maneira de fazer o mesmo:

1) Mesmo passo 1 acima
2) Selecione a opção `File > Project Structure` (existe um botão de atalho na barra de ferramentas `Configure Project Structure` que faz a mesma coisa)
3) Na janela que abrir, no painel mais à esquerda selecione `Libraries`
4) No painel central, selecione o botão `+` para adicionar uma nova biblioteca, selecionando o arquivo JAR que você copiou

No caso da Expansion Library e da Licensing Library (que são sources), após terem sido instaladas via SDK Manager, vá até o diretório onde os *sources* e *resources* destas bibliotecas foram instalados:

No Mac estão em:

- `/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/downloader_library/src`
- `/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/downloader_library/res`
- `/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/zip_file/src`
- `/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/extras/google/play_licensing/library/src`
- `/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/extras/google/play_licensing/library/res`

Copie o conteúdo dos *sources* para `<projeto>/src/main/java`, os *resources* para `<projeto>/src/main/res` e clique no botão `Sync Project with Grade Files`.

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Não, não é um .jar e sim um projeto library, mas obrigado.

Comment: @PedroBacchini, adicionei informações sobre as bibliotecas específicas que você mencionou.

Comment: Para a suport library o ideal é instalar o Android suport Repository no SDK Manager, e incluir a dependencia no build.gradle  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'