# Android Studio - Error:(46, 13) Failed to resolve: me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Boa tarde , tenho um projeto e estou tentando implementar um leitor de QR code.
so que quando vou incluir a lib dele no projeto la no gradle ele da o seguinte erro

> Error:(46, 13) Failed to resolve: me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9

segue o meu gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/java/src','submodules/linphone/java/j2se','submodules/linphone/java/common','submodules/linphone/java/impl','submodules/externals/axmlrpc/src/main/java','submodules/linphone/coreapi/help/java','src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/java/src','submodules/linphone/java/j2se','submodules/linphone/java/common','submodules/linphone/java/impl','submodules/externals/axmlrpc/src/main/java','submodules/linphone/coreapi/help/java','src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/java/src','submodules/linphone/java/j2se','submodules/linphone/java/common','submodules/linphone/java/impl','submodules/externals/axmlrpc/src/main/java','submodules/linphone/coreapi/help/java','src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['submodules/linphone/mediastreamer2/java/src','submodules/linphone/java/j2se','submodules/linphone/java/common','submodules/linphone/java/impl','submodules/externals/axmlrpc/src/main/java','submodules/linphone/coreapi/help/java','src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'

            java.exclude '**/mediastream/MediastreamerActivity.java'
        }


        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')       
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'

}
```

não consigo inserir a lib de jeito nenhum estou indo la em estrutura do projeto e adicionando por la mas quando roda o gradle da o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Bom Dia, tente usar a lib **zxing** https://github.com/zxing/zxing

veja se seguiu esses passos corretamente [Importando biblioteca no Android Studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/491/importando-biblioteca-no-android-studio)